# Scrapy output to json file

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

After working through the official tut I decided to try to build my own spider in the same project. I created parker_spider.py in the spiders directory. which contains:

```
start_urls = [
    "myurl"
]


class Parker_Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "parker"


    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.max_id):
            yield Request('myurl', method="post", headers= headers, body=payload, callback=self.parse_method)



def parse_method(self, response):
    j = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    print(j['d'][0])
```

I can see the correct output being printed out as the spider runs, so I know its working. Now I want to store the output as JSON. When I run:

```
$ scrapy crawl parker -o items.json  
............
2016-05-31 16:53:55 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-05-31 16:53:55 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 16112,
 'downloader/request_count': 26,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 26,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 12484,
 'downloader/response_count': 26,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 26,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 20, 53, 55, 192000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 27,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 26,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 26,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 26,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 26,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 26,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 20, 53, 54, 31000)}
2016-05-31 16:53:55 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

items.json is created in the project directory but it's empty. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: changed spider code as follows:

```
def parse_method(self, response):
    j = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    ParkerItem.account=j['d'][0]
    print(j['d'][0])
    return ParkerItem.account
```

items.py:

```
class ParkerItem(scrapy.Item):
    account = scrapy.Field()
```

Now when I run it I get:

```
 ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'unicode' in <POST myurl
```

Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def parse_method(self, response):
    j = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    item = ParkerItem()
    item['account'] = j['d'][0]
    yield item
```

Comment: Thank you! One question: Why is item available inside the parse_method function? I'm not importing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `parse_method` needs to return an instance of `scrapy.item.Item`, or a subclass. As it is, it returns `None`, which Scrapy interprets as no item could be extracted from the response received.